# check changes before saving into database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 1.11 and DRF 3.6.2 and just started developing an API...

I am trying to check what are the changes to be performed in the database with the data being sent.

```
class IndividualViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Individual ViewSet."""

    serializer_class = serializers.IndividualSerializer
    queryset = models.Individual.objects.all()

    def update(self, request, equipment_serial, pk=None):
        queryset = models.Individual.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = serializers.IndividualSerializer(queryset, data=request.data["entities"][0])
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        old_obj = self.get_object()
        new_data_dict = serializer.validated_data

        if old_obj.name != new_data_dict['name']:
            # logic for different data
            # ...
        serializer.save()
```

However, with the code as above, the perform_update function is never being called by serializer.save() on the update function.

According to the docs, ModelViewSet is inherited from GenericAPIView and it has UpdateModelMixin, which should automatically calls the perform_update function before saving

My questions surrounds on why it is happen and how should I do in order to accomplish the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are overriding the `update` method in your custom viewset. This is the original code for the `UpdateModelMixin` that the `ModelViewSet` mixes in:

```
class UpdateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Update a model instance.
    """
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # refresh the instance from the database.
            instance = self.get_object()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In this original version, `perform_update` is called whenever in the `update` method. If you override that method and still want to call `perform_update`, you need to put it there.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry for reading the docs but not the source code. Totally my fault!
I was in doubt if I must call manually perform_update at my update function... now I can see! Thank you @dukebody!